# z/os DB2 V 9.1 MUTIPLE ROWS INSERT FAIL ERROR CODE -104

Tags: db2, zos

Inserting a single row is successful, but inserting multiple rows is not working.

```
INSERT INTO EMPLYEE(EMPID,EMPNAME,DEPARTMENT,SALARY,DESIGNATION) 
VALUES('1000','XXXXXXX','XX',10000,'SE'),                        
  ('1001','YYYYYYY','YY',9000,'SE'),                         
  ('1002','ZZZZZZZ','ZZ',20000,'MA');
```

Answer (score 0):

DB2 for z/OS doesn't support using a values-list where a full-select would be appropriate. You can use a select like below.  It's a little unwieldy, but it works:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) 
  SELECT val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
  SELECT val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
  SELECT val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL
  SELECT val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```